# PhpStorm - Moving around inside files (Mac)

Tags: phpstorm

I am used to Vim but have been convinced to try out this software, but I am having some difficulties moving around inside of files. For example...

Lets say I generate a html document and get given the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

How would I cycle my cursor from one tag to the next? Say for instance I want to add a title, how can I get my cursor in between the title tags? And after this, how can I then jump my cursor to in between the body tag?

Next question, say I allow autocomplete to finish off my new div, say I type " with my cursor in the middle of the new div?

Thanks chaps!

Comment: Cycling between the tags: there are no hotkeys for this. Some tickets that look related: [WEB-2406](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-2406), [WEB-362](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-362), [WEB-458](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-458)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you install *IdeaVim* which gives you all the vim functionality inside PHPStorm and all the other jetbrains IDEs for that matter.

Here is a [link](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?id=164). You can also install it from phpstorm through

> Settings > Plugins > Browse Repositories > IdeaVim

I've included a picture of how to install it to make things easier for you.

[image]

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you so much for taking the extra time to provide a clip :)

Comment: @WayneHaworth: Well, happy to be of service buddy! :D If you need more help, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: @Games I sat in front of my monitor and wondered why you installed it more than a hundred times.

Comment: @DanLee: Erm, its a gif file, that keeps on looping! :P

Answer (score 1):

Try the AceJump plugin, designed to facilitate navigating inside source code of any kind. There is a video in the documentation explaining the features.

http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7086?pr=phpStorm